# The insert , update and delete et command are default work with Transactions in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, transactions

In `mysql database` the command which we have use to `insert`, `update` and `delete` data are defaultly Transaction ?

```
I mean to say, If we insert 1 corore rows from one table to another and the connection break from some reason, then the half rows are being insert or nothing would be insert?
```

I am confuse here, It work within transaction or not.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h ${SYSTEMIP} -u${SOURCEUSER}  -p${SOURCEPASS} \
 --skip-add-drop-table -t --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --skip-add-locks --complete-insert -e -q --skip-disable-keys \
 --where="id=${ID}" \ ${SOURCEDB} ${SOURCETABLE} | sed -e "s/${SOURCETABLE}/${TARGETTABLE}/g" >> /tmp/sample.sql;
```

from the above script code what is mean --single-transaction ?

Comment: Please anyone answer here!

Comment: What is `1 corore rows`?

Comment: @N.B. this meance more than 1 carore rows are move to another table.

Comment: How to done with shell script.meance how used commit and rollback in shell script

Comment: please tell me /usr/bin/mysqldump -h ${SYSTEMIP} -u${SOURCEUSER}  -p${SOURCEPASS} \
 --skip-add-drop-table -t --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --skip-add-locks --complete-insert -e -q --skip-disable-keys \
 --where="id=${ID}" \ ${SOURCEDB} ${SOURCETABLE} | sed -e "s/${SOURCETABLE}/${TARGETTABLE}/g" >> /tmp/sample.sql; from this what is the --single-transaction.?

Comment: I'm not telling you anything because I don't want to decypher what you meant by `carore`, `corore`, `meance` and other words. You clearly misspelled them and I don't even know what they are. How can I help you if you don't want to take your time and explain what you need help with?

Comment: @N.B. Sorry for misspell. Can you tell me I have  edit question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check autocommit is true/ false.
If autocommit=1 then it will insert record automatically.

Set autocommit false in your setting 
**SET autocommit=0;**

Please refer following link

[Mysql transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Comment: Deddage . this commit and rollback.. How to used in Shell script?